# Prisma create/update without await

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, asynchronous, prisma

I was writing an automation script for DB manipulation in Prisma. I'm using PostgreSQL as my database. I noticed that whenever I omit "await" keyword on database updations, it wouldn't show any error but the database changes are not reflected.

```
// Does not work
prisma.model.create({
  data: {
    name: 'tai',
    schema: {
      abc: 8,
      def: 8,
    },
  }
})
```

But once I use "await", the database does get updated. I skimmed through the documentation but did not have any luck. Can anybody explain the purpose of this behaviour. Also how they managed to implement it.

```
// Works
await prisma.model.create({
  data: {
    name: 'tai',
    schema: {
      abc: 8,
      def: 8,
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 14):

This happens because Prisma queries are then-ables, meaning they only execute when you call `await` or `.then()` or `.catch()`. This is called lazy evaluation. This is different than a regular promise which starts executing immediately. There's an [issue in the Prisma docs](https://github.com/prisma/docs/issues/800) repository about this which you can check out for more information.

**How to implement:** Check out this library: https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-lazy

Comment: I would have hugged you but I'll refrain because of covid.

Comment: Ahaha, happy to help.